# install latest git on RedHat 3

Tags: linux, git, version-control, redhat

Hi I've been searching high and low in the internet where to find a Git installer that will work on our machines at work. They are ATEs that can only run on RedHat3 (which means we can't upgrade the OS).

My limited knowledge on Unix administration is also a big hindrance and the reason that I cannot find a working installer. this is the system information of our machines.

> Linux D10-003 2.4.21-4.0.1.EL #1 Thu Oct 23 01:36:33 EDT 2003 i686
>   i686 i386 GNU/Linux

thanks and looking forward to your answers!

Answer (score 0):

You can install git by compiling source. More steps are at https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git#Installing-from-Source

Comment: Hi @Gaurav I tried that. sadly, this option requires some dependencies to be installed/updated in RedHat 3. Do you know where I can get some RedHat3 compatible:

curl, zlib, openssl, expat, and libiconv

Or better yet, have you tried to install also by source code?

Comment: @SydPao, you can install required dependencies by using your OS' package manager. Or, if you don't have the permissions, ask your admins to do that for you.

Comment: Hi @Gaurav I am not sure about the OS package manager. is that installed with the system? i hope the RedHat Disk is not needed. (sorry really an end user of Linux here, no background on administration of such systems). worst case, what if the dependency for the source code compilation is not in the package manager? is there a way i can add it on RedHat3? What if it is not compatible on RedHat 3, is there a work around?